# Combining two objects into one using JQ where they share the same attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, amazon-iam

I am running an AWS cli command to retrieve all the groups that a user belongs to.
The result from a `iam list-groups-for-user --user-name "User1" | jq '.Groups[] | . += {name: "User1", groups: [.GroupName]} | {name, groups}'` provides the following result:

```
{
  "name": "User1",
  "groups": [
    "group1"
  ]
}
{
  "name": "User1",
  "groups": [
    "group2"
  ]
}
```

What I want to achieve is a more concise result where the group names are all added to a single array owned by a shared attribute, the `name`, for example:

```
{
  "name": "User1",
  "groups": [
    "group1",
    "group2"
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this using `jq`?

Comment: Why are you adding to the items `. += {name: …, groups: …}` to then only extract what you have just added `{name, groups}`?

Comment: Please always include the original (untransformed) JSON input. Not everybody knows what the output of `aws iam` looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how AWS works and what it provides, but based on your current approach you may be looking for an array of unique group names, put into an object alongside with a static string as user name.

```bash
… | jq '{name: "User1", groups: (.Groups | map(.GroupName) | unique)}'
```

If you wanted to parametrize the string, use `--arg`

```bash
… | jq --arg name "User1" '{$name, groups: (.Groups | map(.GroupName) | unique)}'
```

Comment: Thanks pmf, Both your and knittl's answers resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Example output of `aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name Bob` looks like [(docs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-groups-for-user.html):

```json
{
    "Groups": [
        {
            "Path": "/",
            "CreateDate": "2013-05-06T01:18:08Z",
            "GroupId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:group/Admin",
            "GroupName": "Admin"
        },
        {
            "Path": "/",
            "CreateDate": "2013-05-06T01:37:28Z",
            "GroupId": "AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:group/s3-Users",
            "GroupName": "s3-Users"
        }
    ]
}
```

If all you want to do is create an object with a made-up username and a list of group names, then construct a new object with the required properties and use `map` to transform the existing list:

```
{
  "name": "User1",
  "groups": .Groups | map(.GroupName)
}
```

Or a stream & collect approach (this is how `map` is implemented):

```
{
  "name": "User1",
  "groups": [.Groups[].GroupName]
}
```

Output generated when feeding the sample from the official docs:

```
{
  "name": "User1",
  "groups": [
    "Admin",
    "s3-Users"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Knittl, Thanks for your feedback.  
I actually don't want to use a made-up name, that was just an example.  In your particular sample, it would be user Bob. 
My goal is to identify all the groups that an AWS user belongs to.
In any case, both your and `pmf` answer did provide the necessary information for me to resolve my use case.

Comment: @StephanDuToit "made-up" in this case refers to "not part of the input JSON" :) It is external data specified while transforming; it is not in the input itself.